# Update a textbox in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my function I recover a course from a sql database and display its features on a textbox. The idea of this is to then modify it and update the database, but it is like the textbox never changed and always takes the same value as in the Page_load.
Here you have the page_load

```
Titulo.Text = curso.Title;
Description.Text = curso.Description;
```

And then on the On_click function I try to get the new values from the textbox (after modifying it) but I get the same ones I assigned before.
Here is the code

```
curso.Title = Titulo.Text;
curso.Description = Description.Text;
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: WPF or Win Form? And whats the error

Comment: It appears as though you're using ASP.NET web forms (ref. `Page_Load`). If that is the case, please [edit] your question with the appropriate tag(s). While you're editing, feel free to make the letter i uppercase when you are talking about yourself.

Comment: @Steve it is a web page, and the database is working nicely, the problem is that i modify the textbox on the page but when I click the button is like I hadn't changed anything and it gets the previous value

Comment: " i keep getting an error " What error? Please, provide a full error description and stack trace.

Comment: are you calling something to re-show the updated text boxes?
You set the values on load... when you change them are you having it update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Page.Load` event, you need to check if the page is being loaded for the first time, or from a postback (a button click or some other event), or else the values will be re-set to the initial values every time the page is loaded.

```
// set values on first load only
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  Titulo.Text = curso.Title;
  Description.Text = curso.Description;
}
```

Comment: That's it, I didn't know about IsPostBack, thanks a lot!